# Authorization has been denied for this request - Desktop to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-msal

I have been banging my head against a wall for some time now.
Desktop WPF app calling a ASP.NET Web API.
I am using the `[AUTHORIZE]` annotation on the ASP.NET app. This is where the problems have started.
Using MSAL from the WPF app.

```
static App()
    {
        _clientApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
            .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, Tenant)
           .WithDefaultRedirectUri()
            .Build();            
    }
```

ClientId refers to the app registration of the desktop app in Azure.

```
 string[] scopes = new string[] { "api://****-f56f-4cec-a771-dbdb5d43f047/access_as_user" };

                var accounts = await App.PublicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();
                AuthenticationResult authResult;
                try
                {
                    authResult = await App.PublicClientApp
                        .AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                        .ExecuteAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    authResult = await App.PublicClientApp
                        .AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)                           
                        .ExecuteAsync();

                }
```

App registration for the web api is also there. I have set up the scope via 'Expose an API' and given delegated permission to the desktop app to call into the web api.

When I call in I get

```
StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers
```

I can call a non AUTHORIZE endpoint no problem, so the api is working fine.
I have endlessly been through the MSAL documentation.

Things I am unsure about.
AppRoles in the manifest. 
Do they need to be authorised anywhere apart from adding to the manifest?
Do I leave App Service (Web api) as 'Anonymous access is enabled on the App Service app. Users will not be prompted for login.' Is MSAL taking care of that.
I am assuming you can either use MSAL code or secure the api via AD (Authenication/Authorization)

I have dug myself in a hole and can see out right now, so excuse me a little.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

please take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-configure-with-advanced-settings

at the top of that document there is a note saying:

```
Note
The express settings flow sets up an AAD V1 application registration. If you wish to use Azure Active Directory v2.0 (including MSAL), please follow the advanced configuration instructions.
```

basically means that you can't really use msal with the express setup. but can with advanced.

then the section under it describes what you need to do for a desktop app in terms of adding api permissions to your app service.

Hopefully this puts you a bit on the right track, if not please comment further and i will try to help as much as possible.